# Concrete5 Error When Adding Pages

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, concrete5

I just moved my Concrete5 site over from a test server to the live server. However, now I am having problems adding pages. When I click "add blank page" I get the following error:

> An unexpected error occurred. Call to a member function
>   setPageTypeComposerFormLayoutSetControlObject() on a non-object

I have moved the site previously (twice actually) with no issue, but this has popped up since going live yesterday. Not sure even where to begin seeing that I haven't taken a good hard look at Concrete.

I am running on the latest version of Concrete so there is no site.php file that needs to be modified.

What should I do to rectify the problem? Any thoughts would be most helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Is the blank page a custom page_type? i.e. is it a php file within the themes directory?

Comment: There is a page_theme.php, but nothing would indicate that it's blank. Would it default to another page? ie something like landing_no_nav.php?

Comment: Usually when that appears, there is no defined page_type of that page i.e. if "blank page" is not in the page types, it wont be able to use that template

Comment: Dann, how do I go about adjusting that or checking the code?

Comment: go into your custom theme folder and what pages do you see? If you do not see a blank_page, then you cannot make that blank_page in concrete5

Comment: @Dannn, no blank_page in that theme folder. I'm using the same theme on another install and it works fine without that blank_page. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before in the past a couple times. Frequently the result of is the way your database was exported and imported. The `PageTypeComposerFormLayoutSetConttrols` table stores a serialized PHP object. Often this means that when the object was re-imported or exported it had a different length than it did originally (perhaps line endings were replaced or something like that). If you do a PHPMyAdmin export and import using the file created it should work ok; do not open / resave the export file after it has been exported as this may change line endings automatically in some editors.